# Ef core: Sequence contains no element when doing MaxAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm using ef core in my asp core API project.
I have to find the highest order index.

Example:

Data table: `Id, ForeignId, OrderIndex`

So I'm doing:

```
var highestOrderIndex = await _context
                .ExampleDbSet
                .Where(x =>
                    x.ForeignId == foreignId)
                .MaxAsync(x =>
                    x.OrderIndex);
```

The problem is when the example db set is containing 0 elements. This will throw an exception: `Sequence contains no element`.

Is there an elegant way to do this? Because I don't want to get all the elements from the database. And it should be async.

Thanks

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Actually there is quite elegant (and more performant compared to the suggested in the other answer because it's executing just a single database query) way by utilizing the fact that aggregate methods like `Min`, `Max` throw `Sequence contains no element` exception only when used with non nullable overloads, but nullable overloads simply return `null` instead.

So all you need is to promote the non nullable property type to the corresponding nullable type. For instance, if the `OrderIndex` type is `int`, the only change to your query could be

```
.MaxAsync(x => (int?)x.OrderIndex);
```

Note that this will also change the type of the receiving variable `highestOrderIndex` to `int?`. You can check for `null` and react accordingly, or you can simply combine the aggregate function call with `??` operator and provide some default value, for instance

```
var highestOrderIndex = (await _context.ExampleDbSet
    .Where(x => x.ForeignId == foreignId)
    .MaxAsync(x => (int?)x.OrderIndex)) ?? -1; // or whatever "magic" number works for you
```

Answer (score 7):

Doing an `AnyAsync` and then a `MaxAsync` will result in two separate database calls. You can condense it into one by making sure the sequence contains a "default" minimum value. This is a useful trick anywhere you use the Linq Max/Min methods, not just in database code:

```
context.ExampleDbSet
    .Where(w => w.ForeignId == foreignId)
    .Select(s => s.OrderIndex)
    .Concat(new[] { 0 })
    .MaxAsync();
```

Comment: Is the max async executed in the database by SQL query? Is there a sql function that allows to concat something?

Answer (score 6):

Another way with a bit better perfomance than the `MaxAsync`, if the default value is the one you want to get, if there are no results:

```
var highestOrderIndex = await _context.ExampleDbSet
    .Where(x => x.ForeignId == foreignId)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderIndex)
    .Select(x => x.OrderIndex)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

`TOP` is faster than the aggregate functions, look at the execution plan in your SQL Server.

Comment: This is good. We also can use `(int?)x.OrderIndex` in Select to easier handle default value by `??` in this single liner.

Answer (score 4):

You can find if any records exist and if they do, then to find the max. Something like this:

```
var query = _context.ExampleDbSet
                .Where(x => x.ForeignId == foreignId);

var itemsExist = await query.AnyAsync();
int maxOrderIndex = 0;

if(itemsExist)
{
    maxOrderIndex = await query.MaxAsync(x => x.OrderIndex);
}
```

Here you won't have to retrieve all of the items from the database, only check if a record exists which is much much faster and you can also keep the method async.

Comment: Ok. But I will use AnyAsync()

Comment: yep `AnyAsync` will be even better I've updated my answer to use that instead of `CountAsync`.

Comment: You can parse the where query into the anyasync too :)

Comment: doing it the way the answer illustrates doesn't require us to write the same filtering lambda expression logic twice though so if it changes, there's once place to change it at

Comment: I do not recommend this, as it will do two seperate queries to the database (as the validated answer states).

Answer (score 2):

You can use DefaultIfEmpty and Select before MaxAsync.

```
        var highestOrderIndex = await _context
            .ExampleDbSet
            .Where(x =>
                x.ForeignId == foreignId)
            .Select(x => x.OrderIndex)
            .DefaultIfEmpty() // default is 0 if OrderIndex is int or long
             // .DefaultIfEmpty(-1) // default is -1
            .MaxAsync();
```

Comment: This still throws "Sequence contains no elements" for some reason I don't understand. Both the synchronous and the asynchronous version of Max.

Comment: Seems still not solved https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20589